# How to retrieve how many tabs a Pagecontrol has

Tags: delphi

Simple question but i could not find how to.

When i have a TPageControl component, i want to retrieve how many tabs it has, something like this :

```
var i : integer;
begin
for i := 0 to pagecontrol1.pages.count-1 do
    begin
    // mycode for each tab
    end;
end;
```

Is this possible ?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure how you could have missed the answer. There are tons of different ways you could have discovered this, including the documentation. Why would you think this might not be possible?

Comment: @JerryDodge Sorry, i had a bad night of sleep :p

Comment: A simple search for `tpagecontrol count` should have turned up plenty of relevant results. I'm quite surprised at the lack of basic research. Even a simple `F1` to open the help would have lead you to the answer. From a beginner, I would understand. But clearly you're not a beginner at this point.

Comment: @delphirules With 20 downvoted questions consider to let go of programming if one bad night of sleep lets you forget basic workflows.

Comment: @AmigoJack Too late to let it go after almost 30 years

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`PageCount`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TPageControl.PageCount) property of the `TPageControl`:

```
for i := 0 to PageControl1.PageCount - 1 do
begin
  // use PageControl1.Pages[i] as needed...
end;
```

In the future, you can use Code Insight to discover things like this yourself:

[image: Screenshot of the Rad Studio IDE with Code Insight showing the TPageControl.PageCount property]

Comment: @Remy: Are you sure "CodeInsight" should be written without a space? http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Code_Insight

Comment: The help topic on [Background Compilation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Background_Compilation) has it as a single word in one of the bullet points:.  "Use CodeInsight or ErrorInsight.". Does look like elsewhere they are splitting InsightXXX into two words.

Comment: In cases like this, I wonder if it actually helps to hand the OP the answer on a plate.  Might be better to recall the old Borland refrain "Use the source!" (or indeed google or the OLH)?

Comment: @MartynA: I am aware of that issue. In my defence, notice that more than 50% of the vertical extent of this answer is not about the property itself but about how to use Code Insight to discover this. Thus, I try to emphasise your concern. (And the OP might well be rather significantly helped, since it would appear that the OP isn't fully aware of Code Insight and how it can be used.)

Comment: Sure i know the code insight, the answer was in front of me and i didn't see, sorry and thanks !